# Magnetic moment of coordination complexes?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, atoms, coordination-compounds

To understand the commonly quoted magnetic values of coordination complexes (central ion) we use 
$$m_l=\sqrt{n(n+2)} \text{BM where BM}=\frac{e\hbar}{2m_e}\text{JT}^{-1}$$ 
$n$=number of unpaired electrons.

**How did we derive this equation?**

I know the orbital angular momentum of electron is given by $\sqrt{l(l+1)}\hbar$, spin angular momentum is given by $\sqrt{s(s+1)}\hbar$ and the [gyromagnetic ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyromagnetic_ratio) for electron is $$\vec \mu_B=\frac{-e}{2m_e}\vec L$$. There is also the "total" angular momentum given by $n_0\hbar$.

**I fail to see how these magnetic moments and angular momentums are
 related, and how they can be added or related to get the corresponding
 values for an entire atom or a complex?**.

I have also *heard* that the [Lande g-factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land%C3%A9_g-factor) is relevant here.

**Key:-**

$n_0$=principal quantum number, $l$=azimuthal quantum number,$s$=spin (half for an electron), $\hbar=\frac{h}{2\pi}$, $S=\Sigma s+1$(spin multiplicity), $\vec L$=angular momentum, $\vec \mu_B$=Magnetic moment.

Comment: $n/2=s$, $\sqrt{ (n/2)(n/2+1)} = 1/2 \sqrt{ n(n+2)}$...